# Editing print image with edge/chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

I am creating an Edge extension.  When viewing a PDF in the browser, I am able to edit the HTML/CSS and make the changes I would like.  When I hit print, the preview pops up and the changes are gone.  Is there anyway to persist these changes into the printing of the file?  In the Edge browser, you are able to "draw" on the PDF and these changes persist into printing so it seems like its possible but I am not sure how this is being done.  Any help in the right direction would be much appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: There's no way. You can suggest Edge developers to make such an API available for extensions in all of Chromium or at least in Edge.